# How to obtain the Date value from a p:calendar component in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I don't know how to obtain the Date value of a `<p:calendar>` in **PrimeFaces** component using **JavaScript**

This is my component

```
<p:calendar id="calendarInicio"
            widgetVar="horaInicioSpin"
            value="#{hbean.horaInicial}" timeOnly="true" 
            pattern="HH:mm" required="true"/>
```

I need to obtain the hour value of the component because I'm gonna send that value into other `<p:calendar>` component, using **JavaScript**.
Can anyone give me an idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try using `PrimeFaces.widgets['horaInicioSpin']` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PrimeFaces provides a powerful client side API. Make use of it!

1. Add a widgetName to your calendar. This way it is way easier to handle to component on the client side

   ```
   <p:calendar widgetVar="mycalendar" ... />
   ```
2. write your custom JS, using the PrimeFaces client side API

   ```
   <h:form>
        <p:calendar widgetVar="mycal1" timeOnly="true" />
        <p:calendar widgetVar="mycal2" timeOnly="true" />
        <p:commandButton 
         onclick="var d = PF('mycal1').getDate(); d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1); PF('mycal2').setDate(d);" />
   </h:form>
   ```

Inside JS, you are able to modify the returned date according to your requirements and afterwards use the `.setDate()` function to set your date in the other calendar.

Comment: I use your suggestion but I get a `null`. I'm going to search more. Thanks! @stg

Comment: @Marisol Then you are doing sth else wrong. Please see the more detailed example. It's tested and working fine.